# The Image I displayed in view is auto rotated, why?

Tags: iphone, image, internet-explorer, firefox

I am displaying the image by getting image url from the server. it is automatically displayed as rotated.

I checked in the fire fox it is displayed correctly, but when I am saving it in the desktop and then I opened and it is being rotated.

But where as in the internet explorer it displayed correctly in the browser and after saving it .

Answer (score 1):

Generally this issue will happen when image has lost its orientation data.
So before showing the image you have to save them by  `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()`.